# mysql create table not working

Tags: mysql, database

I can create any table I want in mysql and it works, except for creating this table:

```
CREATE TABLE product_shop (
product_id INT NOT NULL, 
shop_id INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (product_id, shop_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
FOREIGN KEY (shop_id) REFERENCES shop(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

I can create this table and it works:

```
CREATE TABLE product_category_junction (
product_id INT NOT NULL, 
category_id INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (product_id, category_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES Category(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Or any other table. Even if I name the product_shop table to something else it won't create it.

When I try to create it, it says :

> #1146 - Table 'the_vegan_repository.product_shop' doesn't exist

and sometimes:

> #2006 - MySQL server has gone away

The product and shop tables do exist with the id field in each. I am doing it in phpmyadmin. What is going on here??

Comment: Table names may be case sensitive on Unix, so make sure you get the table names correct in your `REFERENCES` clauses. It should be `REFERENCES Product(id)`, not `REFERENCES product(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

It must have been because my shop table id had `unsigned` in it. EG

```
CREATE TABLE `Shop` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

I removed the unsigned and then it worked.